# Biblatex citation and bibliography won't display

Tags: biblatex, texmaker, biber

My LaTex compiler is MiKTeX 2.9 (64-bit) on Windows 10. The front-end I'm using to build my document is  [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/). I downloaded the Biblatex back-end Biber, but later found it was already installed within the following path:

C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64

The tex file I'm building "main.tex" along with its bibliography "source.bib" are located within the same path, a folder named "project".

The file "main.tex" has:

```
documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
style=mla,
citestyle=authortitle-terse,
sorting=nty]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{source.bib}

\begin{document}

Some paragraph here \cite{thisref}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

The file "source.bib" has:

```
@book{thisref,
title={A very long title},
author={Name LastName},
publisher={Random publisher},
year={3000},
shorttitle={Long title}
}
```

In Texmaker "Run" is set to "Quick Build" and "View" is set to "View PDF". When I click on "Run" the pdf shows only this:

> Some paragraph here **thisref**

Why is the citation displayed wrong? Why isn't the bibliography showing?

Comment: There is a Texmaker answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 that does pretty much what you did in your answer. If you think it is unclear or could be improved feel free to edit the CW answer there.

Comment: Never download Biber manually. Always use the facilities of your TeX distribution (in your case the Package Manager of MikTeX) to install Biber and `biblatex`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved in 4 steps within Texmaker:

1. Navigate to `Options>Configure Texmaker>Commands>Bib(la)tex` and replace `bibtex %` with `biber %`.
2. Navigate to `Options>Configure texmaker>Quick Build` and check `PdflaTex+Bib(la)tex+PdfLaTex(x2)+View Pdf`.
3. Click "Ok" to close `Configure Texmaker`.
4. Click "Run" icon.